# Accessing webpage using cURL - Issue with redirect

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, cookies

I am trying to access the following URL using cURL:

http://bizsearch.penrithcity.nsw.gov.au/eplanning/Pages/XC.Track/SearchApplication.aspx

However, when I attempt to access the web page I am redirected to:

http://bizsearch.penrithcity.nsw.gov.au/eplanning/Common/Common/terms.aspx

I tried utilizing the following cURL command to get passed this:

```
curl --cookie-jar "CookieTest.txt" url(common terms) -d "ctl00$ctMain1$chkAgree$chk1=on&ctl00$ctMain1$BtnAgree=I Agree"

curl --cookie "CookieTest.txt" url(search application)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to cURL and am having difficulty troubleshooting. I am wanting to pull the XML from the search application page.